# Transactional Replication - table does not have the identity property

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

I have a one way transactional replication set up between two 2005 MS Sql servers.  Recently I have started to receive the following message in the replication monitor from the subscriber:

> Table 'dbo.tblname' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 8106)

Will adding the identity column to 'dbo.tblname' on the subscriber resolve this error or do I need to drop and re-add the subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-adding the subscription did not resolve this issue.  The scheme created replication snapshot agent added a SET IDENTITY_INSERT 'dbo.tblname' ON for record inserts to the insert and update stored procedure.

A manual edit to remove the SET IDENTITY_INSERT 'dbo.tblname' ON from the stored procedures was all that was required.

However this will be an issue when I run the snapshot agent in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add an identity column for no reason.

My guess is someone is issuing a SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON when there is no identity column in this table.

You need to check the code to make sure it is correct.